# Random Variables and covariance

Tags: probability

Suppose two random variables $x$ and $y$ each have a covariance of $-2$; $x$ has mean $7$; $y$ has mean $3$.

What is the expected value of $x+y$?

What is the expected value of $xy$?

If instead $x$ and $y$ were independent of each other, what would be the expected value of $x+y$ and $xy$?

(a). $E[x+ y]=E[x]+E[y]  =  7+3=10$
(b). $E[x y]=E[x]E[y]+Cov(x,y)= 7+3-2=19$
(c). i)  $E[x+ y]=E[x]+E[y]  =  7+3=10$

ii) $E[x y]=E[x]E[y]+Cov(x,y)= 7+3-2=19$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except for the last item. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=21$.